# PHP code issue - login and registration

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newbie to PHP and MySQL, and I have used this code to create a registration and login page.

the database is **dbusers** with:

- id (PK, Auto Increment, Int(10) )
- username (Unique, Varchar(16))
- password (Varchar(16))
- email (Varchar(45))

Here is the code for **register.php** (uses a form which is not relevant):

```
// dbConfig.php is a file that contains your
// database connection information. This
// tutorial assumes a connection is made from
// this existing file.
include ("dbconfig.php");


//Input validation and the dbase code
if ( $_GET["op"] == "reg" )
{
$bInputFlag = false;
foreach ( $_POST as $field )
{
if ($field == "")
{
$bInputFlag = false;
}
else
{
$bInputFlag = true;
}
}
// If we had problems with the input, exit with error
if ($bInputFlag == false)
{
die( "Problem with your registration info. "
."Please go back and try again.");
}

// Fields are clear, add user to database
// Setup query
$q = "INSERT INTO `dbusers` (`username`,`password`,`email`) "
."VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."', "
."PASSWORD('".$_POST["password"]."'), "
."'".$_POST["email"]."')";

// Run query
$r = mysql_query($q);

// Make sure query inserted user successfully
if ( !mysql_insert_id() )
{
die("Error: User not added to database.");
}
else
{
// Redirect to thank you page.
Header("Location: register.php?op=thanks");
}
} // end if


//The thank you page
elseif ( $_GET["op"] == "thanks" )
{
echo "<h2> Thanks for registering!</h2> ";
}

// EOF
?>
```

The code for **login.php** (to deal with the form @ another file which is not relevant):

```
<body>

    <?php
    session_start();
    // dBase file
    include ("dbconfig.php");

    if ($_GET["op"] == "login")
    {
    if (!$_POST["username"] || !$_POST["password"])
    {
    die("You need to provide a username and password.");
    }

    // Create query
    $q = "SELECT * FROM `dbusers` "
    ."WHERE `username`='".$_POST["username"]."' "
    ."AND `password`=PASSWORD('".$_POST["password"]."') "
    ."LIMIT 1";

    // Run query
    $r = mysql_query($q);

    if ( $obj = @mysql_fetch_object($r) )
    {
    // Login good, create session variables
    $_SESSION["valid_id"] = $obj->id;
    $_SESSION["valid_user"] = $_POST["username"];
    $_SESSION["valid_time"] = time();

    // Redirect to member page
    Header("Location: home.php");
    }

    else
    {
    // Login not successful
    die("Sorry, could not log you in. Wrong login information.");
    }
    }
    ?>

</body>
```

And the beginning code on my first page **home.php**:

```
<body>

<?php
    session_start();

    if (!$_SESSION["valid_user"])
    {
    // User not logged in, redirect to login page
    Header("Location: login.html");
    }

    // Display Member information
    echo "<p>User ID: " . $_SESSION["valid_id"];
    echo "<p>Username: " . $_SESSION["valid_user"];
    echo "<p>Logged in: " . date("m/d/Y", $_SESSION["valid_time"]);
?>

<div id="MENUBAR">
<ul id="LINKS" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
    <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu">Clientes</a>
      <ul>
```

Now the questions:

1) what does the and $_SESSION["valid_id"] = $obj->id do what is "->" symbol and why is it pointing to id (@**login.php**)?

```
 if ( $obj = @mysql_fetch_object($r) )
        {
        // Login good, create session variables
        $_SESSION["valid_id"] = $obj->id;
        $_SESSION["valid_user"] = $_POST["username"];
        $_SESSION["valid_time"] = time();
```

2) Why do i get keep getting an invalid login? there are multiple users created (and written) successfully on the above mentioned database, but i still get the same error...

Thanks in advance.

Alex.

Answer (score 0):

1)
The lines validates if a login can be found from the SQL query written earlier. If so, some values are added to the current session.
The `->` is a object operator - it enables you to access object methods and variables. In this case your object is `$obj` and it's accessing the variable named `id` in that object.

If you are used to work with other OOP languages, it would be equivalent to a structure like this:
`int MyId = MyObject.id;`

2)
There could be a lot of reasons. First off, the script is vulnerable to SQL injection. Secondly, you haven't told how the users were created. Your SQL query tells us that your passwords should be passed through MySQL's password() function - did you create your users' passwords in the same way?

A simple way of checking if your SQL query would produce any results is to echo it out, copy and paste it into the database (ie. through phpMyAdmin). If so, the problem lies within your code.

**UPDATE**
Sergiy T. points out that session_start() has been placed after output has been sent to the browser. Since you haven't been warned about this, you probably havent enabled error reporting. While developing, this should be on.
It's important, session_start() is placed before any output at all (even whitespaces).

A tip along the way - stop supressing errors with the `@` operator; this could potentially reveal your problems while developing.

And again - **make sure your scripts arent vulnerable to SQL injection!**

Comment: the password's where created through a register.php file with the PASSWORD function. 
They are written as passes (double checked) in the **dbusers** database.

Comment: You should add the register.php to your question - this makes the question better.

Comment: the password's where created through a register.php file with the PASSWORD function. 
They are written as passes (double checked) in the **dbusers** database.
Everything else is working and the problem must lye in either login.php or home.php...

Comment: I believe removing the error supressor and pasting your SQL query directly to the database could reveal your problem.

Answer (score 0):

the -> syntax is used for PHP objects. id is part of $obj, and you access it using the -> syntax.

As to why it isn't working, I don't see anything obvious, but there are a lot of issues with your code. For starters, you are storing passwords in plaintext, and you aren't sanitizing the inputs from the form. This leaves you open to huge issues with SQL injection, and are just the two easiest and most obvious attacks on your code.

Implementing an authentication is hard, and not recommend for any developer working alone. There is no good reason to reinvent the wheel here, there are plenty of good free options available to integrate into any project you have. I like the [symfony](http://symfony.com) framework, but there are plenty of others around.

Answer (score 0):

There is already answer for the first question.

For second question - there is possibility of sql-injection. Probably someone just chose username or password with ' or " in it.

And there may be something wrong with `session_start()` (take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

Comment: I didn't see the problem with session_start() - nice catch. If the general error reporting is disabled, this will not be revealed for OP.

Comment: Unless you're using some output buffering, `<body>` tag will be sent to browser before `session_start()` is called.

Comment: Agreed - but using output buffering for fixing problems like header warnings should be discouraged.